# I keep getting the error pygame.error: Unsupported image format, im using a png and I can't find any info on this

Tags: python, pygame

I've been looking for solutions to this problem and I can't find any that work, I've been using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w at about 22 minutes he adds the character my code is

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#title and iconp
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

#player
Player = pygame.image.load('Ship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

def player():
    screen.blit(playerImg, (playerX, playerY))

running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 128, 155))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player()
    pygame.display.update()
```

and my error is pygame.error: Unsupported image format. If you could help it would be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps `Ship.png` isn't actually a valid PNG file - we don't have any way to tell.  Can you view it in any other software?

Comment: Are you on M1 Mac? How did you install pygame?

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and I can view the ship png in paint but that's about it, It's 1.21kb 64x64 and 24bit color if that helps

Answer (score 0):

see! playerImg has been defined so i think you use Player instead of playerImg that and tell me wat happens

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you meant, it keeps giving me an error for line 12 and nothing I change about how stuff is defined fixes it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You use different names for the variables, `Player` and `playerImg`.

Use the same name when you load the image and when you use it:

```py
playerImg= pygame.image.load('Ship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

def player():
    screen.blit(playerImg, (playerX, playerY))
```

Or add arguments to the `player` function:

```py
Player = pygame.image.load('Ship.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

def player(playerImg, x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

running = True
while running:

    # [...]

    player(Player, playerX, playerY)

    # [...]
```